# What's the status of flaka?

Tags: ant, flaka

I'm considering adding [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) to our Ant builds to get the EL support, but I'm concerned that the last release is from June 2011.  There's not a whole lot of chatter about it on its own website or anywhere else I can find, either.

This *could* mean it's fulfilling its purpose in life with great success so no need to make new releases, or it could mean it's not healthy.

Anyone know for sure?

Comment: I feel much the same about flaka as I do about ant contrib... you're way better off with native ant, until you can't and from there you'll want to write your own tasks for anything you can't get done easily.  I've seen a lot of ant-contrib/flaka madness that leads to an unmaintainable mess.  If your able to, I'd suggest looking into gradle and breaking up with ant.  You'll like it.

Comment: I'm not a fan of ant contrib by any means, I'm spending much of my time in my refactor getting rid of the mess of <if> and <switch> conditionals added by others.  IMHO Flaka suffers from a similar problem: in the wrong hands it could get bad.  But I do find the EL expression support compelling, offering a way to simplify some of the synthetic targets that we use for compound conditions and such.  We already have a lot of custom tasks.  As for Gradle: also a huge fan, but in the case we're somewhat stuck with what we've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This could mean it's fulfilling its purpose in life with great success so no need to make new releases, or it could mean it's not healthy.*

We believe that Flaka is very healthy. Those who believe otherwise may express their concerns here in this thread.

Similar, those who enjoy Flaka and would like see further (exiting) features, please step forward and discuss with us your wishes.

Comment: Is that a "we" as in "dedicated user" or as in "project committer?"

Comment: That "we" is a project committer (project initiator).

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure => i'm participating in the Flaka project
Using Flaka successfully for over 3 years in production code, starting with Ant 1.7.1 and Java 6,
 currently using Ant 1.9.1 and Java 7.
So, to use your own words "it's fulfilling its purpose in life with great success"
Nevertheless i believe Flaka has even more potential, see [Adding EL Functions](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/AddingELFunctions)
Still a lot of people use AntContrib although their [latest release 1.0b3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/) is from 2006-11-02 and using AntContrib before i know that Flaka has many advantages, f.e. overwriting of userproperties or inline EL expressions that are not possible with AntContrib.
@thekbb => when starting with a new project as a Groovy affinicado i would use Gradle, but if i'm stuck with ant i would use Flaka.
Although because of personal reasons there has been no new release since June 2011 it doesn't mean we're not around anymore ;-) Maybe more next year..
And as already said before, Flaka 1.02.02 works great with Ant 1.9.x :-)